# ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification is not work in ios5.0

Tags: assetslibrary

The ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification is not working in IOS 5.0.  It works fine in the older IOS 4 version.  How can I get it to wrok in IOS 5.0?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question that fits yet?

Answer (score 3):

It is an [ios5.0 Bug](http://www.openradar.me/10484334).

you can do one of the following:

1.) Call [self.assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { }]; immediately after creating instance of ALAssetsLibrary

2.) Observe ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification (not NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification)